# Modify properties of a control SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm new using `SwiftUI` and I don't know how can I make that a `Button` changes properties of a control, for example, another `TextField`.

for example:

```
HStack {
    SecureField("Password",
                text: $password)
        .frame(width: 330,
               height: 50,
               alignment: .bottomLeading)
        .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
    Button(action: {}) {
        Image(systemName: "eye.fill")
            .frame(width:10,
                   height:10)
            .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
            .fixedSize()
    }
}
```

I want to see my current password when I press the `Button`, but I don't know how to call my `SecureField` because I don't have an ID
(using Swift I could make an `IBOulet` and `IBAction` but I don't know how to do that on `SwiftUI`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it is done in some dedicated view, to which you transfer password string from some view model, etc., the approach could be as follows

```
struct DemoShowPassword: View {
    @Binding var password: String
    @State private var showPassword = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            if showPassword {
                TextField(" Password", text: $password) .frame(width: 330, height: 50, alignment: .bottomLeading)
                    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
            } else {
                SecureField(" Password", text: $password) .frame(width: 330, height: 50, alignment: .bottomLeading)
                    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
            }

            Button(action:{
                self.showPassword.toggle()
            }){
                Image(systemName: "eye.fill")
                    .frame(width:10, height:10)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                    .fixedSize()
            }
        }
    }
}
```